# Multiple client program

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy

I was wondering if I have a single server application and a bunch of clients connected. What if the first client asks for some data and then in the middle of that the second client asks for data. What would happen? Will the first client connection be broken?

I am using IndyServer Indy Client TCP.

Comment: All network connections are different.

Comment: `"Will the first client connection be broken?"` - Not if you did it right. I think you need to tell us how you did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TCP server opens a port where clients can connect. A connection is defined by the four components client IP / client port / server IP / server port.

Indy TCP servers process connections in separate threads. So as long as your connection processing code is thread-safe, the processing will be separated and the threads will not interfere with each other.